# ¿Cual es el error en este fragmento de código? AutoHotkey Script

Tags: variables, autohotkey

Estuve tratando de corregir la expresión, pero no comprendo bien la función de cada operador

```
b := u ^ 1 & i // (1 << c++) . b
```

> Warning: This variable has not been assigned a value.

[image: Error en la variable]

Comment: Hola, mira la documentación de los operadores: https://autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm#Expression_Operators_in_descending_precedence_order

Answer (score 1):

Sobre los [operadores](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm#Expression_Operators_in_descending_precedence_order):

```
; ^ OR Exlusivo
; A     B   A ^ B
; 0     0     0
; 0     1     1
; 1     0     1
; 1     1     0

u := 0
b := u ^ 1 
Msgbox %b%
; Resultado 1

; ----------------------------------

; & AND
; A     B   A & B
; 0     0     0
; 0     1     0
; 1     0     0
; 1     1     1

i := 1
u := 0
b := u ^ 1 & i
Msgbox %b%
; Resultado 1

; ----------------------------------
; ++ Aunmenta en 1 para la siguiente iteración

c := 1
b := c++
b := c + 1

Msgbox %b%
; Resultado 3

; ----------------------------------
; << Bit shift left, cambio de bit a la izquierda
; https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xftzc7e(v=vs.100).aspx


b := 14 << 2

Msgbox %b%
; Resultado 56


; ----------------------------------
; . concatenar

b := 1 . 0

Msgbox %b%
; Resultado 10

; ----------------------------------
; // Floor divide 

b := 9 // 2

Msgbox %b%
; Resultado 4
```

Sobre tu "error", realmente es una advertencia que te dice que `b` no tiene asignado un valor, el programa puede ejecutarse con esa advertencia, si no la quieres ver comenta la linea `#Warn` al inicio de tu script.

demo:

```
;#Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.

u := 1
i := 0
c := 1
; b := 1
b := u ^ 1 & i // (1 << c++) . b

Msgbox %b%
; Resultado 1
```